# How to get button CallbackQuery in conversations of telethon library

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon

I am learning about `asyncio` to use `telethon` module. I want to use buttons in conversations and get the output of the button selected by user.

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True, pattern=r'start'))
async def chatbot(event):
   sender = await event.get_sender(); SENDER = sender.id
   async with bot.conversation(SENDER) as conv:
   await conv.send_message('Select a button :')
   await conv.send_message('Yes or no?', buttons=[
        Button.inline('Yes!', b'yes'),
        Button.inline('Nope', b'no')    ])

   if selected_button == 'yes' :
        # do something
   else:
       # do something
```

Using [callbackquery](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.callbackquery.CallbackQuery) as given in the docs, jumps to the `handler(event)` function of `events.CallbackQuery()`. But does not go back to the `conv` of `chatbot` function.

How can I get the selected button info and proceed further in the `chatbot` function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Telethon v1.11, you need to use [`Conversation.wait_event`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.conversation.Conversation.wait_event), which is a bit ugly but does the trick:

```py
# Defined somewhere
def press_event(user_id):
    return events.CallbackQuery(func=lambda e: e.sender_id == user_id)

...

# Later in your conversation
press = await conv.wait_event(press_event(SENDER))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working pretty good for a user chat.     But when I try in it telegram channel to take input from the members. It does not respond, just shows rotating circle. In my code, in case of message event from telegram channel , I have changed variable  `SENDER = int(str(event.to_id).split('=')[1].replace(')',''))`. How can I get the selected button info in this scenario ?

Comment: You probably need to `await press.answer()` like you would in a normal callback query, and make sure `logging` is enabled too.